# bitnami Postgresql 16.2 Password authentication failed for user Role does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, bitnami

I'm trying to run bitnami/postgresql:16.2.0 docker image, but no luck.

Here are the steps:

1. stop container, delete container, clean "data" directory

`docker stop RR15 ; docker rm RR15 ; rm -rf ~/containers/postgres16.2/data/`

2. here is my custom `pg_hba.conf` (only 2 lines not commented):

   host    all             all                 0.0.0.0/0               md5

   host    all             all                 127.0.0.1/32            md5
3. run docker

`docker run --name RR15 -p 5432:5432 -v ~/containers/postgres16.2:/bitnami/postgresql -v ~/containers/postgres16.2/conf:/bitnami/postgresql/conf -e POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=user1 -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=pwduser1 -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=postgres -e POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres bitnami/postgresql:16.2.0`

so

- POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=user1
- POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=pwduser1
- POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=postgres
- POSTGRESQL_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres. (more [info about this param](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/postgresql))

As soon as I execute the command it starts and stops, looks fine ... no issues, full detail here:

```
postgresql 19:03:04.46 INFO  ==> 
postgresql 19:03:04.46 INFO  ==> Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 19:03:04.46 INFO  ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
postgresql 19:03:04.46 INFO  ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
postgresql 19:03:04.47 INFO  ==> Upgrade to Tanzu Application Catalog for production environments to access custom-configured and pre-packaged software components. Gain enhanced features, including Software Bill of Materials (SBOM), CVE scan result reports, and VEX documents. To learn more, visit https://bitnami.com/enterprise
postgresql 19:03:04.47 INFO  ==> 
postgresql 19:03:04.48 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
postgresql 19:03:04.50 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
postgresql 19:03:04.52 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 19:03:04.52 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 19:03:04.53 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf detected
postgresql 19:03:04.53 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf detected
postgresql 19:03:08.14 INFO  ==> Starting PostgreSQL in background...
postgresql 19:03:08.26 INFO  ==> Changing password of postgres
postgresql 19:03:08.27 INFO  ==> Stopping PostgreSQL...
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
```

I'm stating the container again and so far it looks good:

```
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.78 INFO  ==> 
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.79 INFO  ==> Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.79 INFO  ==> Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.79 INFO  ==> Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.79 INFO  ==> Upgrade to Tanzu Application Catalog for production environments to access custom-configured and pre-packaged software components. Gain enhanced features, including Software Bill of Materials (SBOM), CVE scan result reports, and VEX documents. To learn more, visit https://bitnami.com/enterprise
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.79 INFO  ==> 
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.81 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL setup **
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.82 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_* env vars..
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.83 INFO  ==> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.83 INFO  ==> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.84 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf detected
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.84 INFO  ==> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf detected
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.86 INFO  ==> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.86 INFO  ==> Loading custom scripts...
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.87 INFO  ==> ** PostgreSQL setup finished! **
2024-03-18 12:03:14 
2024-03-18 12:03:14 postgresql 19:03:14.88 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.901 GMT [1] LOG:  pgaudit extension initialized
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.921 GMT [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.922 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.922 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.925 GMT [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.934 GMT [55] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-03-18 19:03:08 GMT
2024-03-18 12:03:14 2024-03-18 19:03:14.944 GMT [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Now I'm trying to connect as user1 with pwduser1 to postgres:

[image: connect as user1 with pwduser1 to postgres]

```
2024-03-18 12:05:49 2024-03-18 19:05:49.737 GMT [62] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user1"
2024-03-18 12:05:49 2024-03-18 19:05:49.737 GMT [62] DETAIL:  Role "user1" does not exist.
2024-03-18 12:05:49     Connection matched file "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf" line 96: "host    all             all                 0.0.0.0/0               md5"
```

Same for postgres with password "postgres" to postgres DB:

[image: postgres with password "postgres"]

```
2024-03-18 12:04:33 2024-03-18 19:04:33.260 GMT [60] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2024-03-18 12:04:33 2024-03-18 19:04:33.260 GMT [60] DETAIL:  User "postgres" has no password assigned.
2024-03-18 12:04:33     Connection matched file "/opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf" line 96: "host    all             all                 0.0.0.0/0               md5"
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here, and I'm trying to find the cause. I could use a bandage-like solution, such as connecting and changing passwords, or using "trust" for localhost. However, I prefer to create a correct Docker command.

I had the same setup for v15.4, and it worked just fine. It feels like the issue is connected with volume mapping.

Any help is appreciated!

## update

After looking at the [Rabban Keyak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183060/701869)'s answer I played a bit more and find out that if I exclude `pg_hba.conf` everything works as it should

The package itself generates this content for `pg_hba.conf`:

```
host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host     all             all             ::/0                    md5
local    all             all                                     md5
host     all             all        127.0.0.1/32                 md5
host     all             all        ::1/128                      md5
```

However, changing the content to this ^^ doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Not like instantly, but in about 15 minutes i've done repeating your case.

Differeces:

- Using `podman` instead of `docker` (doesn't have the last one installed nearby)
- Using port 55432 on the host system instead of 5432 (the last one is busy already for me)
- Using `--mount` instead of `-v`, and it's option `U=true` to achieve apropriate rights for directories
- Using `scram-sha-256` hash instead of `md5`

After all of that i was able to connect the server using psql.

```bash
[admin200 /]$ podman version
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.9.0
API Version:  4.9.0
Go Version:   go1.21.6
Built:        Wed Jan 24 13:07:27 2024
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
[admin200 /]$ cd ~/
[admin200 ~]$ TMPDIR=$(mktemp -p$(realpath .) -d)
[admin200 ~]$ cd ${TMPDIR}
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ mkdir basedir
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ mkdir conf
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ echo 'host all all 0.0.0.0/0 scram-sha-256' > conf/pg_hba.conf
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ podman run -d \
--name pb16 \
-p 127.0.0.1:55432:5432 \
--mount type=bind,source="${TMPDIR}/basedir",destination=/bitnami/postgresql,U=true \
--mount type=bind,source="${TMPDIR}/conf",destination=/bitmani/postgresql/conf,U=true \
-e POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=user1 \
-e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=la50360329x \
-e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=database1 \
docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:16.2.0
56ea65776fd187c86f960a4d74cffeef9d5fdffbe7d3194c40df44cb8a153aa4
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ PGPASSWORD=la50360329x PGSSLMODE=disable psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 55432 -U user1 -d database1 -c '\l'
                                                       List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Locale Provider |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | ICU Rules |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------
 database1 | user1    | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            |           | =Tc/user1            +
           |          |          |                 |             |             |            |           | user1=CTc/user1
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            |           | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            |           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                 |             |             |            |           | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | libc            | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            |           | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                 |             |             |            |           | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ sudo ls -la basedir/data/
total 96
drwx------ 19 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 ..
-rw-------  1 201000 domain users    3 Mar 19 00:08 PG_VERSION
drwx------  6 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 base
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:09 global
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_commit_ts
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------  1 201000 domain users 2640 Mar 19 00:08 pg_ident.conf
drwx------  4 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_logical
drwx------  4 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_notify
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_replslot
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_serial
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_snapshots
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_stat
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_twophase
drwx------  3 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_wal
drwx------  2 201000 domain users 4096 Mar 19 00:08 pg_xact
-rw-------  1 201000 domain users   88 Mar 19 00:08 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------  1 201000 domain users  249 Mar 19 00:08 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 201000 domain users   79 Mar 19 00:08 postmaster.pid
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ podman stop pb16
pb16
[admin200 tmp.TMsoFC5xs8]$ cd ..
[admin200 ~]$ rm -rf ${TMPDIR}
```

The image you are using is fine seems. The problem seems like somewhere behind of my changes.

Comment: Thank you, sir! You've helped me realize that if I exclude pg_hba.conf, everything works as it should. The issue lies either with the file or the mapping. I'm inclined to believe it's the mapping